# Search for 2 things at once with LinkText

Tags: c#, selenium, webdriver

I'm making an "item finder", for supreme website, and my code works to click on the piece of clothe. But it just clicks on the first item in the row -> [it picks the pink one, because its the first in the row](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1cUTC.png)

**Code**

```
    {
        IWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.Url = "http://www.supremenewyork.com/shop/all/jackets";

        driver.Manage().Window.Maximize();

        driver.FindElement(By.LinkText("Polka Dots Rayon Work Jacket")).Click();
```

}

How could i do, so it also takes in its search the color, so it will click on the jacket for example, with the color aswell?

the HTML code of the jacket name: `<a class="name-link" href="/shop/jackets/que2rcwml/qft89kxy0">Polka Dots Rayon Work Jacket</a>`

the HTML code of the jacket color: `<a class="name-link" href="/shop/jackets/que2rcwml/qft89kxy0">Light Pink</a>`

Comment: https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/dotnet/html/M_OpenQA_Selenium_Remote_RemoteWebDriver_FindElements.htm there is a method that returns a list

Comment: that doesnt seem to fix my question, so should i maybe do, so if the FindElement by link text to be partial, and run that code, if color is true to what i have set the color to be? or what should i do? Thank you.

Comment: @NikolajEgelundJørgensen Please read why a [screenshot of HTML or code or error is a bad idea](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors). Consider updating the Question with formatted text based relevant HTML, code trials and error stack trace.

Comment: Done, Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use XPath to get you want, for example

`//article[.//a[text()='Black']]`  will find out clothes which color is `Black`,

Now we need to add restriction to find wanted clothe by name from above all Black clothes as following:

`//article[.//a[text()='Black']]//a[text()='Polka Dots Rayon Work Jacket']`

```
IWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();

driver.Url = "http://www.supremenewyork.com/shop/all/jackets";

driver.Manage().Window.Maximize();

var color = "Black"
var clothe = "Polka Dots Rayon Work Jacket" 
var xpath = string.format("//article[.//a[text()='{0}']]//a[text()='{1}']", color, clothe)

driver.FindElement(By.XPath(xpath)).Click();
```